# What's happening with this code in gcc-4.8?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, constexpr

Errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'constexpr int fib(int)':
main.cpp:6:42: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     return (n < sizeof(ftbl)/sizeof(*ftbl)) ? ftbl[n] : fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
                ^
/tmp/cch0aLwI.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf): undefined reference to `std::cout'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2d): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3c): undefined reference to `std::cout'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x43): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5a): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x69): undefined reference to `std::cout'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x70): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x87): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)'
/tmp/cch0aLwI.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xaa): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb9): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It executes without a problem in clang.

The example was taken from page 312 of B.Stroustrup's new book "TCPL".

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int ftbl[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
constexpr int fib(int n)
{
    return (n < sizeof(ftbl)/sizeof(*ftbl)) ? ftbl[n] : fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << fib(1) << '\n';
    std::cout << fib(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << fib(6) << '\n';
}
```

Compiler invokation: `gcc-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -pedantic -pthread -Wall main.cpp && ./a.out`

Comment: use g++ instead of gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b157d362791bec4

Comment: @stefan Perfect. I'll accept this as answer.

Comment: there's not actually the need for an answer here, as the fix is simply typographic. Users with the same problem probably won't find this Q/A, but ask their own question. Therefore, I would suggest to close this question (I already flagged it).

Comment: To fix the unsigned warning and to be thorough, add another ? operator to check for n < 0 else cast to unsigned and return the answer. Because, what would your expression do if you passed -1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Alternatively, you can link the standard library if you want. You need to put it at the end though because of linking order.

```
gcc-4.8 -x c++ -std=c++11 -O2 -pedantic -Wall -pthread main.cpp -lstdc++  && ./a.out
```

Comment: `-x c++` tells the compiler to treat files specified on the command line as C++. [It's not necessary when the file extension is one the compiler recognizes as C++ by default, such as `.cpp`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb98aa2dca09ae32)